# X past X, Y to Y

Tags: mathematics, time

While sitting in the waiting hall a wall clock caught my attention. I realise there are only 15 minutes left for the conversation that will determine my path in life. I then took a glance at my watch. **I realise they show different times.** In my watch it is **X past X**, however in the wall clock it is **Y to Y**. **It occured to me that after a 1000 minutes there will be 555 minutes between these two. What is X+Y?**

PS: Both of these are 12 hour analog clocks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... After 1000 minutes, won't the difference be the same as now?

Comment: Usually practice is to accept the [first](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51920/30903) answer that is correct.

Comment: @boboquack I know but the way was nice in the second one, however if that causes any problem I can undo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The difference between the two times is 555 minutes, which is 9 hours 15 minutes.
>
> Looking only at the minute hand, there must therefore be a 15 or 45 minute difference between them. The minute hand difference between **X past _** and **Y to _** is **X+Y**, so **X+Y=15** or **X+Y=45**. The latter would lead to **X>12** or **Y>12** which is not possible since they should also represent one of the hours of a clock.
>
> Therefore **X+Y=15**.
>
> This is all the question asks for, but we can actually work out the time completely.
>
> Now look at the whole hours. There is a difference of 9 hours between them, so you would expect **|Y-X|=9** or **|Y-X|=3**. I ignored the minutes here, and doing so could make the real difference one hour more or less. However, from the previous equation the sum **X+Y** is odd, so the difference **|Y-X|** must also be odd, and cannot be off by one.
>
> Solving the two equations, we get 4 potential solutions:
>
>  y=3, x=12
>
>  y=12, x=3
>
>  y=6, x=9
>
>  y=9, x=6
>
> This gives the times:
>
>  `3  to  3, and 12 past 12:  2:57, 12:12`
>
>  `12 to 12, and  3 past  3: 11:48,  3:03`
>
>  `6  to  6, and  9 past  9:  5:54,  9:09`
>
>  `9  to  9, and  6 past  6:  8:51,  6:06`
>
> The second and third of these don't have a difference of 9:15 but of 8:45, so are invalid.
>
> 1000 minutes is equal to 16 hours and 40 minutes, or +4:40. The two potential solutions are then
>
>  `Y to Y    X past X     After 1000 minutes` 
>
>  `2:57      12:12     :  7:37  4:52`
>
>  `8:51       6:06     :  1:31 10:46`
>
> The second of these can be considered to have a difference of 9:15 without adding/subtracting 12 hours. So the best solution is:
>
>  **9 to 9 and 6 past 6**
>
> Nevertheless, the solution **3 to 3 and 12 past 12** is valid too if you allow the difference to span across the 12 hour mark.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> X+Y=**15**.
>  **X=6** and **Y=9**, or as clock times, **6 after 6** (6:06), and **9 to 9** (8:51).
>
>  6:06 + 1000 minutes (16h 40m) is 10:46.
>  8:51 + 1000 minutes is 1:31.
>  555 minutes (9h 15m) separates 1:31 and 10:46  (1+9=10, 31+15=46).